# How to route pages on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

Hello guys I just started to learn Angular JS  and I have a problem on loading the content from pages. I don't receive any content. This is my index and my js code:

index.html

```
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <title>My App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <h1>Text 1</h1>
            <h2>Text 2</h1>
            <nav>
                <a href="#/">Home</a>
                <a href="#/exterior">Exterior</a>
                <a href="#/interior">Interior</a>
                <a href="#/gallery">Gallery</a>
                <a href="#/form">Form</a>
                <a href="#/live-preview">Live</a>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <div ng-view>
            <!-- Content here -->
        </div>

        <footer>
            2015
        </footer>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular-route.js"></script>
</body>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routes) {

  $route.when('/',{
    templateUrl : '/views/index.html'
  });

  $route.when('/exterior',{
    templateUrl : '/views/exterior.html'
  });

  $route.when('/interior',{
    templateUrl : '/views/interior.html'
  });

  $route.when('/gallery',{
    templateUrl : '/views/gallery.html'
  });

  $route.when('/form',{
    templateUrl : '/views/form.html'
  });

  $route.when('/live-preview',{
    templateUrl : '/views/live-preview.html'
  });

  $routes.otherwise({
    redirectTo : '/'
  });

}]);
```

My all pages are already created as files and the content is like this

exterior.html

```
<div>
    <h2>Exterior</h2>
    <p>My content here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Just wondering instead of $routes put $routeProvider.

Comment: Just wondering as well why didn't you chain the methods together?

Comment: i receive this in console [Error] Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: Have you tried to change $routes to $routeProvider?

Comment: yes and is getting the same error

Comment: Is your app.js in js folder? Your main module is not loaded as you showed the error. So, your app won't work.

Comment: Is that the only error in your console? Everything looks good.

Comment: everything is going in the specified folder

Comment: http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.9/$injector/nomod?p0=app
ensure@https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular.js:1688:45
module@https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular.js:1762:20
https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular.js:4094:35
forEach@https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular.js:323:24
loadModules@https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular.js:4078:12
createInjector@https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular.js:4004:22
doBootstrap@https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular.js:1446:34
bootstrap@https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular.js:1467:23

Comment: @logicltd Are you still facing the problem?

Comment: and some this kind of errors from angular.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in these below lines

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular-route.js"></script>
```

You are including app.js before having angular.js and angular-route.js libraries.

Include this at the bottom and check again

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
```

There is one more error in your script: You are calling $route instead of $routes.

Let me know if it is useful

Comment: now I get this error Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: /views/exterior.html

Comment: check if this template exists

Comment: my all templates are going in views folder and all are there

Comment: Are other views getting displayed ?

Comment: no one is showing is getting just a new error for each one

Comment: This error occurs when $compile attempts to fetch a template from some URL, and the request fails.

To resolve this error, ensure that the URL of the template is spelled correctly and resolves to correct absolute URL. The Chrome Developer Tools might also be helpful in determining why the request failed.

If you are using $templateCache to pre-load templates, ensure that the cache was populated with the template.https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/tpload

Comment: got it I've added a "/" before "views"

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you build you `.config` like so:

```
app.config( function($routeProvider) {

  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
    templateUrl : '/views/index.html'
  })
    .when('/exterior', {
    templateUrl : '/views/exterior.html'
  })
    .when('/interior', {
    templateUrl : '/views/interior.html'
  })
    .when('/gallery', {
    templateUrl : '/views/gallery.html'
  })
    .when('/form', {
    templateUrl : '/views/form.html'
  })
    .when('/live-preview', {
    templateUrl : '/views/live-preview.html'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo : '/'
  });

});
```

Comment: @logicltd How about now? I changed some stuff

Comment: Alan that will throw errors. Take out semi-colons to chain methods.

Comment: So is changing the page I can see this in address bar but is not showing the content

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed them, I edited the initial question code rather than writing it out again and didn't spot the semi-colon's for chaining

Comment: @logicltd Try again with the updated code (no semi-colon before .when)

Answer (score 0):

angular.module('moduleName',['ngRoute']);

check the dependence and add source file angular-route.js in index.html